# locally scoped extern idiom

Tags: c++, c, scope, extern

I'm writing a scientific program with lots of knobs. Rather than constantly add and remove command-line options, I've been adding scoped `extern` variables for extra bits of configuration. These variables are used only in one local scope, and defined together in a dedicated source file `args.cpp`. That file includes no headers, so it only takes a second to recompile it and relink the executable to change any options.

```
// big_slow_compiling_source.cpp:

{
    extern double fudge_rate;
    quantity += correction * fudge_rate;
}

// args.cpp:

/* Configuration for big_slow_compiling_source.cpp: */
double fudge_rate = 3.2;
```

Is there a name for this idiom? I've been calling them "local externs" to myself but there must be better terminology.

Any known pitfalls?

Comment: 1. Why are you using global variables?  2. Why aren't you declaring them normally in a header file?  3. The usual pitfalls apply: If the two files go out of sync, you'll get mysterious linker errors (if you're very lucky), runtime crashes (if you're lucky), or just weird program behavior.

Comment: @melpomene The answer to all these questions is that each variable is only used in one place. The way I declare them guarantees that. I could accidentally remove one from the file but still define it in `args.cpp`, I suppose. But any other error I can think of would be flagged by the linker.

Comment: It guarantees nothing. You can do `extern int foo; foo = 42;` anywhere.

Comment: @melpomene Why would I assign to a configuration variable? I suppose making them `const` would "fix" that..

Comment: OK, then you can still `extern int foo; do_stuff_with(foo);` anywhere. How exactly does not declaring them in a header file "guarantee" anything?

Comment: @melpomene I know that each variable is used in only one place. If they were in a header I could use them without adding a cumbersome declaration at every use (would be bad), but more significantly this way I can completely eliminate one without remembering to change a header. (And without a dedicated configuration header for each source, such changes would cause other slow files to recompile.)

Comment: This has nothing to do with C. Why do everybody use both tags at the same time almost everytime :(

Comment: @Eregrith It has nothing specifically to do with C++. I tagged both because it works in both, and I happen to be writing in C++.

Comment: Why not use PHP, Ruby, Python, and other language tags then? Pick a language and ask practice-relevant questions for this one. Even if C and C++ are close on this matter, they are still different and may offer different drawbacks to the same method.

Comment: @Eregrith Do any of those languages have the same `extern` keyword and scope semantics as C and C++? I don't think so. And C and C++ aren't just close here, they're identical. It makes no difference whatsoever which you choose.